# Excel VBA (via JavaScript) - Moving a Sheet to a new location

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

With the following code, I am attempting to move a Sheet in my Excel workbook from one location to another.  However, instead of making the move - Excel creates a new Workbook.  How do I move a Sheet from one location to another within the same Workbook?

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                       //
// function serviceInitExcel($scope)                                     //
// Version:                                                              //
// Description: Initialize Excel Spreadsheet                             //
// Date:                                                                 //
// To Do:                                                                //
// Author:                                                               //
//                                                                       //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var serviceInitExcel = function() {

    var _SCFR;

    var _filename = "emptyServiceValue";
    var _serviceBrowser = "";

    var service = {};

    service.soundOff = function() {

        alert("Another generic method");

    }

    service.initExcel = function() {

        var _scfr = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            _scfr.Visible = true;
            _scfr.Workbooks.Add;

        // alert("Application Initialized: " + _scfr.Name);

        _SCFR = _scfr;

        return _SCFR;

    } // genericMethod

    service.createSheet = function(iWorkbook, sheetName) {

        var pblSheet = iWorkbook.Sheets("Payable");
            pblSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Payable Sheet";

        var newSheet = iWorkbook.Worksheets.Add;
            newSheet.Name = sheetName;

            newSheet.Select

            newSheet.Range("A1").Value = "_SCFR.Name: "     + _SCFR.Name;
            newSheet.Range("A2").Value = "ActiveWorkbook: " + _SCFR.ActiveWorkbook.Name;
            newSheet.Range("A3").Value = "Sheet 1: " + _SCFR.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name;
            newSheet.Range("A4").Value = "Sheet 2: " + _SCFR.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name;
            newSheet.Range("A5").Value = "Sheet 3: " + _SCFR.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Name;

            newSheet.Range("A6").Value = "testSheet: " + iWorkbook.Sheets("testSheet").Name;
            newSheet.Range("A7").Value = "Payable: "   + iWorkbook.Sheets("Payable").Name;
            newSheet.Range("A8").Value = "Paid: "      + iWorkbook.Sheets("Paid").Name;

            for (var s=0; s < 500; s++) {

                newSheet.Range("A9").Value = s;

                newSheet.Select

                iWorkbook.Sheets("Payable").Select

            }

            iWorkbook.Sheets(newSheet.Name).Move + "After:=" + iWorkbook.Sheets("Payable");

            // newSheet.Move + "After:=" + iWorkbook.Sheets(3);

            // Sheets("Payable").Select
            // Sheets.Add
            // Sheets("Sheet6").Select
            // Sheets("Sheet6").Move After:=Sheets(3)

            // _SCFR.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("testSheet").Move + "After:=" + _SCFR.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Payable");

        return iWorkbook;

    } // genericMethod

    return service;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
newSheet.Move(null, iWorkbook.Sheets("Payable"))
```

Comment: This answer completely solved it!  What is the MAXIMUM acknowledge that I can give you?  You really helped me out here.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you take out the concatenation it will work fine. Try this:

`iWorkbook.Sheets(newSheet.Name).Move After:=iWorkbook.Sheets("Payable")`

Comment: I may have implemented this incorrectly, but I got - TypeError: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: @DougFranklin Sorry, I was completely wrong, please see my revised answer.

Comment: No problem at all.  Getting rid of the quotes gives me a new error: SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' 
12serviceInitExcel.js, line 73 character 41
SCRIPT5009: 'serviceInitExcel' is undefined 
controllers.htm, line 272 character 5
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: serviceInitExcelProvider <- serviceInitExcel <- controllerTestController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/unpr?p0=serviceInitExcelProvider%20%3C-%20serviceInitExcel%20%3C-%20controllerTestController

Comment: Just to clarify, you used the line I put above, right? You didn't just take out quotation marks?

Also, I can't help you with that error sadly, I only know VBA and not Javascript :(

Comment: I used the line you put above, yes - copied it and pasted.  Many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you better. Hopefully a javascript expert comes along.